How is called this animation? And what the implementation might be on Flutter
help please to find out how this animation is called.
And maybe anyone know how to implement this on Flutter?
Firstly this button is located on bottombar, and when you press - you can swipe it to the top of the screen and call some function.
I`ve created stack widget and inside it I have my bottom bar and positioned this button. But I need also implement animation


demo: https://www.loom.com/share/563716219ccc42dd9e41c14d167883d7
code: https://github.com/jbjason/animations_anatomy/tree/main/lib/screens/challenges_/bank1_chlng
